# How to salvage data from Heroku Postgres

Tags: postgresql, heroku, data-recovery

we are using Heroku Postgres with Ruby on Rails 3.2.

A few days before, we deleted important data by mistake using 'heroku run db:load' with misconfigured data.yml, that is, drop tables and the recreate tables with almost no data.
Backup data is only available 2 weeeks before, so we lost data of 2 weeks.
So We need to recover not by PG Backup/pg_dump but by postgresql's system data files.

I think, the only way to recover data is to restore data from xlog or archive file, but of course we don't have permission to be Super User/Replication Role to copy postgres database on heroku (or Amazon EC2) to local server.

Is there anyone who confronted such a case and resolved the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your only option is the backups provided by the PgBackups service (if you had that running).  If not, Heroku support might have more options available.

At a minimum, you will have some data loss, but you can guarantee you won't do it again ;)

Comment: Neil, Thank you for your answer. We set up the PGBackups, so it would not happen just like the case happened.